# Search between two dates in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

Hi I want to search the items present in the table users. The code I wrote is

```
$fromdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['fromdate']));
$todate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['todate']));

$s="SELECT * FROM logs WHERE dt BETWEEN $fromdate AND $todate  ORDER BY dt DESC ";
$x = mysql_query($s);
```

But the output is not showing. Please someone help me.

Comment: try with $s="select * from logs where dt between '$fromdate' and '$todate'  order by dt desc ";// you forget quotes in your query

Comment: You need to put $fromdate and $todate in quotes. Avoid writing php variables directly in sql statement.

Answer (score 1):

Need to apply quotes around `'$fromdate'` and `'$todate'` as

```
$s="SELECT * FROM logs WHERE dt BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' ORDER BY dt DESC ";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fromdate = strtotime($_POST['fromdate']);
$todate = strtotime($_POST['todate']);

$query="SELECT * FROM logs WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(dt) BETWEEN $fromdate AND $todate  ORDER BY dt DESC ";
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).